# Firebase "auth/network-request-failed" error in ajax request on electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I try to sign in firebase on web (electron framework) . When I try to call the metod  as following , I get error. This code is called on click event of button ( it is not form or submit )

```
 const email ="yunus@scp.com"
  const password = "deneme"
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function () {
    const database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(ref).set(payload).then(function () {
      console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Synchronization failed');
    });
  })
```

Ajax response:

```
 {
    a: null
    code: "auth/network-request-failed"
    message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurr
}
```

In request header as following. the origin protocol is file:// . it may cause this problem. if so how to solve this problem
Request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: file://
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SCP/1.29.3 Chrome/76.0.3809.146 Electron/6.1.4 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Version: Node/JsCore/7.18.0/FirebaseCore-web
```

Note:Also when try request on postman , I can get successfull response

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't really do "AJAX" from the application's perspective.  It's just using the API provided by the Firebase SDK.  And the error suggests that the SDK thinks you don't have a working network connection.  If you want to catch this error, you should have a `catch` callback chained after the `then` callback you have now.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have already catch the error. The main problem why get this error on electron while I dont get error on postman